# Javascript - How to access object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with store in this variable `report[sales]` which contain information such as all, amount, month as an object.

When i tried to console log the following `console.log(report[sales])`, i received the result of `{All: 1, amount: 855, month: 2}`.

But when i want to access the value for All which I tried the following `report[sales].All` the result is `undefined` and I also tried `report[sales]["All"]`.

** Edit **

Result of `console.log(report)`
{Feb: {All: 1, amount: 855, month: 2, …}}

Result of `console.log(report[sales])`
{All: 1, amount: 855, month: 2, …}

I want to access value of `All`

Comment: have you tried `report.sales.All` are you 100% `All` starts with a capital and its not 'all'

Comment: Ya I am 100% sure that is ```All```. as I tried ```console.log(report[sales])```. i get ```{All: 1}```. ```report.sales``` result is ```undefined```.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson that's bracket notation, the variable `sales` doesn't necessary have `"sales"` as value.

Comment: @zy can you screenshot your code and the response

Comment: console the report object and and also check type of that variable using typeof(report["sales"]) is it object or string.

Comment: is there any way you can create a [mre] to clearly show your issue? You can use a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to help do so.

Comment: Is report an object or an array? Reading report[sales] I would say an array. Use 'report.sales.All'

Comment: @Spangle Report is array. I tried using report.sales.All but it is not working using report.sales.All

Comment: @S_Sky Yes i have checked it is object for ```report[sales]```

Comment: Please update your question to include an example of what the report array looks like and I will be able to assist :)

Comment: @Spangle I have uploaded images to show the content of ```report``` and report[sales]

Comment: Hi, rather than upload the pictures, please just add the text so that I can copy it to test.

Comment: @Spangle Hi I have changed it to text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const report = {
  sales: {All: 1, amount: 855, month: 2}
}

console.log(report.sales.All);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `console.log(report.sales.All);` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the text to your question. I have no idea where you got `sales` from based on the info you provided, but below is a couple examples on how to log out the value of All. Another thing, you stated that report is an array, however it actually is an object based on your console.log in your question.

```js
let report = {Feb: {All: 1, amount: 855, month: 2}, March: {All: 2, amount: 855, month: 2}}
// Just log out the Feb.All value
console.log(report.Feb.All);
// A for in loop is an easy way to loop over objects
for(let i in report) {
  // This will log out all the All values in the object.
  // Just swap out All with amount or month to print the other values.
  console.log('All = ' + report[i].All);
}
```